# To understand monkey patching in Javascript

Tags: javascript, monkeypatching

I am trying to understand the concept behind how monkey-patch works in JavaScript?

I've gone through too many examples but couldn't able to understand

***For example - Monkey patching the dispatch function in Redux***

```
let next = store.dispatch
store.dispatch = function dispatchAndLog(action) {
  console.log('dispatching', action)
  let result = next(action)
  console.log('next state', store.getState())
  return result
}
```

Source: http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html#attempt-3-monkeypatching-dispatch

> Can anyone please explain monkey patching in simple terms and example

And which is the best scenarios to use it?

Thanks.

Comment: To understand it in simpler way refer this website : https://davidwalsh.name/monkey-patching

Answer (score 4):

Let say you use a library which define a class Test with a method test.

If you want to monkey patching-it you have to use this kind of code and include it **after** the library :

```
// replacing current implementation with a new one
Test.prototype.test = function(arg1, arg2, ...){...}
```

Now let say you want to do something a bit smarter, like adding something to the function without modifying the rest here is how you would do it :

```
var oldFN = Test.prototype.test;
Test.prototype.test = function([arguments...]){
    [...some custom code...]
    oldFN.apply(this, arguments);// arguments keyword refer to the list of argument that your function recevied, if you need something else use call.
    [...some custom code...]
}
```

Monkey patching is valid but must be used wisely. Furthermore each time you upgrade the library, you must check that all your patches works still fine.