# Javascript - Can we override JSON.parse function

Tags: javascript

Is there a way using which we can override the JSON.parse function ?

If yes then please provide me the direction to override it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is monkey-patching in JavaScript? How is it executed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37020630/what-is-monkey-patching-in-javascript-how-is-it-executed)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes I tried using following and it is working -

var JS_JSON_PARSE = JSON.parse;

JSON.parse = function(a){
        //Write custom code
 return JS_JSON_PARSE(a);
}

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(JSON, 'parse')
> {writable: true, enumerable: false, configurable: true}
```

Like this

```
(function(JSON) {
   var oldParse = JSON.parse;

   JSON.parse = function newParse() {

   } 
}(JSON))
```

Answer (score 2):

The following should do the trick:

```
JSON.parse = function(str) {
    return { 'foo': 'bar' };
};

var res = JSON.parse('aaaa');
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will be helpful to you

```
JSON.prototype.parse= function(str)
{
    // your custom code should be here
}
```

Or you can make Custom JSON class for achieve actual JSON feature

```
function CustomJSON() {};
CustomJSON.prototype = new JSON;
CustomJSON.prototype.__super__ = JSON;
CustomJSON.prototype.parse= function(str) {
    console.log('called CustomJSON.parse');

    // calling JSON.parse();
    this.__super__.prototype.parse.call(this);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

In my application in all of the places i have used JSON.parse function and now i dont want to go and change code at every place to call custom function. So i am planning to use following way. Please let me know if it is a good practice or it will cause any issues -



`var JS_JSON_PARSE = JSON.parse;

JSON.parse = function(a){
        //Write custom code
 return JS_JSON_PARSE(a);
}`

Comment: Okey, no problem, but if you like my answer, don't forget to up vote it.